# WSN Packages in Matlab

Tags: matlab, routes, protocols

I want to simulate my protocol in Matlab. I do not know about any toolbox nor i get any information about WSN coding in Matlab.

I want to know about it.

regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use Low Energy Adaptive Clustering Hierarchy (LEACH) cluster based routing protocol in WSN:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25853-wireless-networks

And you can write your own simulator using the MATLAB scripting language. Examples:

[SimEvents](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simevents/), [Prowler](http://www.isis.vanderbilt.edu/projects/nest/prowler), [TrueTime](http://www.control.lth.se/attic/truetime/) and [Complex Networks Package](http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/Networks/ComplexNetworksPackage.html)

Hope this helps.